# Newbie to hardhat, I am able to make transactions to smart contract but when I return a data it complains: Calling an account which is not a contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I am a complete newbie in hardhat, web3 and smart contracts. I wrote a simple sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract CreatorRegistry {
    struct Creator {
        address walletAddress;
        string name;
        string b64Image;
    }

    Creator[] public creators;
    mapping(address => bool) public isCreatorRegistered;

    function signup(address _walletAddress, string memory _name, string memory _b64Image) public {
        require(!isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress], "Address is already registered");

        Creator memory newCreator;
        newCreator.walletAddress = _walletAddress;
        newCreator.name = _name;
        newCreator.b64Image = _b64Image;

        creators.push(newCreator);
        isCreatorRegistered[_walletAddress] = true;
    }

    function getCreator(uint256 _index) public view returns (
        address walletAddress,
        string memory name,
        string memory b64Image
    ) {
        require(_index < creators.length, "Invalid index");

        Creator storage creator = creators[_index];
        walletAddress = creator.walletAddress;
        name = creator.name;
        b64Image = creator.b64Image;
    }

    function getCreatorCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return creators.length;
    }

    function getCreatorByAddress(address _walletAddress) public view returns (
        address walletAddress,
        string memory name,
        string memory b64Image
    ) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < creators.length; i++) {
            Creator storage creator = creators[i];
            if (creator.walletAddress == _walletAddress) {
                walletAddress = creator.walletAddress;
                name = creator.name;
                b64Image = creator.b64Image;
                return (walletAddress, name, b64Image);
            }
        }

        // Creator not found
        return(walletAddress, "Not Found", "Not Found");
    }
}
```

And here's how I am invoking it in my frontend app:

```
const getContracts = async (): Promise<{
    error: boolean;
    message?: string;
    data?: { creatorContract: Contract; registrationContract: Contract };
}> => {
    const { ethereum } = window as Web3Window;
    if (!ethereum)
        return {
            error: true,
            message: 'Please install metamask extension and try refreshing the page',
        };
    try {
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        const creatorContract = getSmartContract(
            contentCreatorAddress,
            contentCreatorABI,
            signer
        );
        const registrationContract = getSmartContract(
            creatorRegistryAddress,
            creatorRegistryABI,
            signer
        );

        return { error: false, data: { registrationContract, creatorContract } };
    } catch (err) {
        return { error: true, message: (err as { message: string }).message };
    }
};
```

Now I am using registrationContract as follows:

```
const getCurrentUser = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (registrationContract && account) {
            console.log('Account = ', account);
            const user = await registrationContract.getCreatorByAddress(account);
            console.log('User = ', user);
        } else console.log('No smart contract');
    };
```

But this fails in browser with:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: could not decode result data (value="0x",
```

And solidity console in my localhost says:

```
  WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
  From:        0xdf3e18d64bc6a983f673ab319ccae4f1a57c7097
  To:          0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512

eth_blockNumber (21)
```

However when i try to create user which returns nothing as per signup function, it succeeds:

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Transaction: 0x80413c4906fbcc6d60abebe3ba42c3772e8f72f0376513da6e47aa281a816738
  From:        0xdf3e18d64bc6a983f673ab319ccae4f1a57c7097
  To:          0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512
  Value:       0 ETH
  Gas used:    22404 of 22405
  Block #1:    0x3710cec86a1ddfc3a182885d68939ebcb80eb832122c10a78a009c982d8037b4
```

Can someone help me find out what's going wrong here?